# Gst parse_launch syntax error with gst-launch-1.0 working

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm trying to run my gstreamer pipeline in python code instead of using gst-launch-1.0. This works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=2560,height=720,framerate=60/1 ! tee name=t ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=0 brightness=50 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3 -v
```

However when I run

```
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=2560,height=720,framerate=60/1 ! tee name=t ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=0 brightness=50 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3 -v")
```

I get as syntax error code

```
GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: syntax error (0)
```

other pipelines work so I believe I setup and imported everything correctly. Not sure what's special about this pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-v` at the end is bogus and not part of the pipeline.